# Make Objective-C realize block return type

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, block, boolean

I have some Obj-C code in which I have a class with many blocks as members.
The property in question is the following:

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) BOOL(^truthPredicate)(int, NSMutableDictionary*);
```

And is implemented in a `@synthesize` statement in the `.m` file. In one of the `init` methods for the class, I tried to set the property to a literal block:

```
truthPredicate=^(int val, NSMutableDictionary* params) {return val >= MANodeTruthThreshold ? YES : NO;};
```

This signals a compiler error. The compiler, despite the fact that `YES` and `NO` are defined to be `(BOOL)1` and `(BOOL)0`, and `BOOL` being defined as `signed char`, the compiler insists that I'm trying to assign an `int` returning block to a `BOOL` returning variable. How do I make Obj-C realize that I'm returning `BOOL`s, not `int`s?

Comment: There's a known issue with LLVM/Clang where `char`-width return types on blocks have some unexpected behaviour. You're not crazy. :)

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan: Thanks. I'm just starting Obj-C after some time with C++, so its kind of annoying to have the compiler trying to deduce types incorrectly when I could just tell it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, type inference is failing you. Try the more verbose syntax:

```
truthPredicate=^ BOOL (int val, NSMutableDictionary* params) {return val >= MANodeTruthThreshold ? YES : NO;};
```

Comment: Thank you SOOO much. I have been having a lot of truble with this, and I didn't just want to have to hack something. I knew there was a real solution. Thanks!